# Getting the first and last timestamp for a packet type in a pcap file using python

Tags: python, timestamp, analysis, packet, pcap

I am pretty much a rookie at python, I have this small script to print out the number of packets for 3 different protocols (tcp, udp and igmp) I want to be able to print the first and last timestamp of each protocol type, as you can see from the code below, I currently have placeholder timestamps but this is temporary, does anyone know how I would get the first and last timestamp for the 3 protocol types?

```
counter=0
ipcounter=0
tcpcounter=0
udpcounter=0
igmpcounter=0


filename = 'basic-packet-file.pcap'

for ts, pkt in dpkt.pcap.Reader(open(filename,'rb')):


    counter+=1
    eth=dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)
    if eth.type!=dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
       continue

 

    ip=eth.data
    ipcounter+=1

 

    if ip.p==dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP: 
       tcpcounter+=1
 

    if ip.p==dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP:
       udpcounter+=1

    if ip.p==dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_IGMP:
       igmpcounter+=1
       


print ("\t Total number of packets in the pcap file: ", ipcounter)
print ("\t Protocol type: \t Number of packets: \t Mean packet length \t First timestamp \t Last timestamp ")
print ("\t TCP: \t\t\t", tcpcounter, "\t\t\t Testmean", "\t\t 00:00", "\t\t\t 00:00")
print ("\t UDP: \t\t\t", udpcounter, "\t\t\t Testmean", "\t\t 00:00", "\t\t\t 00:00")
print ("\t IGMP: \t\t\t", igmpcounter, "\t\t\t Testmean", "\t\t 00:00", "\t\t\t 00:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create 3 lists of timestamps 1 for each of TCP, UDP, and IGMP, You could then sort each list by timestamp and get the total number of each kind of packet by calculating the length of each list.

The example below shows what you'd need to do for just the TCP packets but the logic will be the same for UDP and IGMP.

```py
TCP_timestamps = []
packets = []

for ts, pkt in dpkt.pcap.Reader(open(filename,'rb')):
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)
    if eth.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
        continue
    
    packet = eth.data
    packets.append(packet)

    if packet.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP: 
        TCP_timestamps.append(ts)

TCP_timestamps.sort()


number_of_tcp_packtes = len(TCP_timestamps)
earliest_TCP = TCP_timestamps[0]
latest_TCP = TCP.timestamps[-1]
```